# phpmyadmin password set

Tags: password

I am trying to set a password for my phpmyadmin.my config.ini file is

```
<?php
/*
 * Generated configuration file
 * Generated by: phpMyAdmin 3.4.10.1 setup script
 * Date: Sun, 22 Jul 2012 11:33:17 +0000
 */

/* Servers configuration */
$i = 0;

/* Server: localhost [1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['nopassword'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'triple';


/* End of servers configuration */

$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '500be38d07a469.36176220';
$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en';
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
?>
```

but the problem is, it letting me in using whatever input as password.like(khfjsdhfj).whats wrong?How can I set it?just for information previously i did not have any password to log in.

Answer (score 1):

The password is saved in the database. You can set the Permissions on your database with a query like this:

```
GRANT <permissions> ON <database>.<table> TO <user> IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '<password>';
```

You can also try to set the permissions and password with PHPMyAdmin. Look out for the database permissions and set a password there.

The reason why PHPMyAdmin logs you in is that you set

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['nopassword'] = true;   <-- If password fails try 
                                                username and empty Password
...
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'triple';
```

And you obviously don't have a password on your DB